# Statistics collection related values do not increase in OMNeT++

Tags: omnet++, veins

In order to measure the packet transmission/reception count, I declared a scalar variable and wrote a function related to record. It looks like this:

**A.h**

```
class VEINS_API A : public DemoBaseApplLayer
{
     private:
          long StaticsFrsaPacketCount;

          cOutVector frsaPacketCountVector;
     ...
}
```

**A.cc**

```
void A::initialize(int stage)
{
     DemoBaseApplLayer::initialize(stage);
     if(stage == 0)
     {
          StaticsFrsaPacketCount = 0; 
          frsaPacketCountVector.setName("fR_SA packet count");
          ...
     }
}

void A::finish()
{
     recordScalar("fR_SA Packet", StaticsFrsaPacketCount);
     ...
}

void A::handleSelfMsg(cMessage* msg)
{
     switch(msg -> getKind())
     {
          case SEND_FRSA_EVT:
          {
               ...
               StaticsFrsaPacketCount++; 
               frsaPacketCountVector.record(StaticsFrsaPacketCount);
               ... 
               sendDelayedDown(wsm, uniform(0.01, 0.50));
          }
          ...
     }
}
```

I wrote the code by referring to the statistics written in the official OMNeT++ `Tictoc` tutorial. However, the result of the scalar value through the generated `.anf` file after the simulation is finished is as shown in the image below.

[image]

In other words, it seems that the value is incremented `1` time and not incremented after that. What is the cause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(this part) of your code looks fine. The most likely reason why you have 1 in the result because really just one packet was sent. The statistics are showing what is actually happening. If you expect several packets to be sent, I suggest to start the app in Qtenv and step over the simulation and make sure that it works as you expect.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. As answered, there was a problem with the code logic. The `scheduleAt()` function is missing. So, it was confirmed that only one statistical data inserted unconditionally when running the simulation.